# How to reset ng-model variables to Null in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-select

In AngularJS, I have the following sample code:

```
<select style="margin-left:5px;width:60px" id="product" ng-model="output.product">
<select style="margin-left:5px;width:60px" id="status" ng-model="output.status">
```

Within my UI screen, I have a button where the user can reset select drop-down values for both `product` and `status` but I am unsure how to reset both my ng-model scope output values to null for `output.product` and `output.status`.

I have tried `scope.output = "";` but this doesn't seem to work.

Again, I have using AngularJS (v1.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to write an answer for AngularJS V1.1 because that version is no longer supported. See [AngularJS Version Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status).

For version 1.7, reset the select by setting the model to `null`:

```
  $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.choice.product = null;
      $scope.choice.status = null;
  };
```

### The DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choice = {};
  $scope.productChoices = ['product A', 'product B', 'product C', 'product D', 'product E'];
  $scope.statusChoices = ['active', 'pending', 'completed', 'cancelled'];

  $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.choice.product = null;
      $scope.choice.status = null;
  };   
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  Select a product:
  <select ng-model="choice.product" ng-options="prd for prd in productChoices">
      <option value="">Select a product</option>
  </select>
  <br/> Select a status:
  <select ng-model="choice.status" ng-options="prd for prd in statusChoices">
      <option value="">Select a status</option>
  </select>

  <hr/> selected product: {{choice.product}}
  <br/> selected status: {{choice.status}}
  <br/>
  <button type="button" ng-click="reset()">
    Reset
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple things... the code below should help, else you can share where you're at:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  $scope.output = {
    'product': "",
    'status': ""
  }
  $scope.productChoices = ['product A', 'product B', 'product C', 'product D', 'product E'];
  $scope.statusChoices = ['active', 'pending', 'completed', 'cancelled'];
});
```

```css
select {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  Select a product:
  <select style="margin-left:5px;width:60px" id="product" ng-model="output.product" ng-options="prd for prd in productChoices">
  </select>
  <br/> Select a status:
  <select style="margin-left:5px;width:60px" id="status" ng-model="output.status" ng-options="prd for prd in statusChoices">
  </select>

  <hr/> selected product: {{output.product}} <br/> selected status: {{output.status}}<br/>

  <br/>
  <button type="button" ng-click="output = {'product':'', 'status': ''}"> Reset
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try what you have suggested here as the way it seems to be working at the moment is keeping the previous values that were selected. Will let you know.